# How to use Django button as form input field?

Tags: django

I am trying to use a button in order to change the font size on my application. I have a ModelForm that saves the font size.

What I cannot do is use a button as input for the font size.

The buttons

```
<form method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="submit" name="btn" value=11>
 <input type="submit" name="btn" value=12>
</form>
```

Normally i would do:

```
form.save()
```

in the view.py however I am not sure how to do this for a button...

Here is the view.py

```
     def test_view(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = fontform(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             val = form.cleaned_data.get("btn")
             --HOW DO I SAVE BUTTON VAL HERE USING .save()????---
     else:
         form = fontform()
     return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT
Here is the model:

```
class layout(models.Model):
    font = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

The Form:

```
class fontform(forms.ModelForm):
   btn = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
       model = layout
       fields = ['font']
```

Comment: is it possible to show the code for the model and forms ??

Comment: @KwakuKusi i have added them above

Comment: and **form.save()** doesn't work ??

Comment: @KwakuKusi unfortunately not